# Cannot access SAP url using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap

I am trying to get data from a SAP link using the below code. But when trying to access the response using `GetResponse()` I am getting an error. Please suggest a possible fix or an explaination to why I am getting this error.

```
 string url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SAPurl"]; 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    string username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SAPuserID"];
    string pw = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SAPpassword"];
    string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes( username  + ":" + pw ));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
    //More lines of code added  
    System.IO.Stream aStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    StreamWriter aStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(aStream); 

    aStreamWriter.Write(xmlString); //xmlString is generated as the below xml
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // This line throws error
```

**Extra code**: The `xmlString` is generated as below. I believe this is where the actual 400 error code is pointing to. All values inside tags are confirmed to be correct.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <add:To>AAA</add:To>
    <add:Action>BBB</add:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <SAPRequest>
    <header>
    <applicationName>CCC</applicationName>
    <userId>DDD</userId>
    <password>EEE</password>
    <server>FFF</server>
    <client>GGG</client>
    <systemNumber>HHH</systemNumber>
    </header>
    <body>
    <interfaceName>III</interfaceName>
    <listOfSomething>
    <number>1000001</number>
    <number>2000001</number>
    <number>3000001</number>
    <number>4000001</number>
    </listOfSomething>
    </body>
    </SAPRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The error is as below.

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

NB: This was a previously working code but now it is not working.

Comment: just a general idea, did you verify the link is still correct? Maybe some parameter necessary that was optional before? Essentially, maybe a change on the server side prompted this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If this code was working (and had been verified) and you are now getting an error indicating that it is happening on the remote server, then, assuming you are not in control of the remote server, you need to ask that server administrator for guidance.

An error has occurred on the server.  It could be anything (transient blip/newly deployed code requiring a change/server down) - you need to ask for more details.

Comment: Well I just joined the support team for this application and I have no idea what was happening before (no one to ask too :( ). The user said he is not able to access this page due to this error. I guess this would need to go to another team who has the server access. Thanks anyway. EDIT: I will mark as answer if nothing comes up in a day.

Comment: Another issue came up with some code added. The edit is made to the actual post.